# Is There A Way to NPM Install Compass and Still Run it at the Command Line?

Tags: npm, compass

With most NPM packages you can invoke their command line application by running it from the `bin` folder inside the package's folder in `node_modules`:

```
npm install foo
./node_modules/foo/bin/foo
```

Now of course you can do this more easily if you install the package globally:

```
npm install -g foo
foo
```

but that's generally considered to be a bad practice.

With the `compass` package however this doesn't appear to be the case.  When you do:

```
npm install compass
```

the package's `node_modules` directory doesn't even have a `bin` folder.

So, my question is, is there anyway to install compass non-globally, but still be able to invoke it from the command line?

P.S. I know I could also install compass through the system, ie. `sudo apt-get install compass`, but I was hoping I could keep my process simple and have NPM manage everything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out the answer is no, because the `compass` NPM package doesn't actually include compass.  Rather, the package is a JS front-end to the compass executable, which must be installed separately.  Presumably this is because compass relies on Ruby, and they didn't want to make Ruby a package dependency.

So if you want to use Compass it will have to be part of the system-level (on Linux, `apt-get install`) setup.

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a bunch of time [thinking I was] troubleshooting a docker container....

Comment: Whenever I solve my own problem I wonder if I should just delete it instead of answering myself ... but then I get comments like this one and I know I made the right choice :)